# Can someone prove $\sum_\limits{k=1}^n \frac{1} {n+k} \geq \frac{1} {2}$ with mathematical induction

Tags: induction

Can someone prove, for $n \in \mathbb N, n\geq 1,$ $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^n \frac{1} {n+k} \geq \frac{1} {2}$$ with mathematical induction?

Here is where i struggled:

Induction beginning: $n=1$

$$\sum_\limits{k=1}^1 \frac{1} {1+k} \geq \frac{1} {2}$$

$$\frac{1} {2} \geq \frac{1} {2} \quad \checkmark$$

Supposition: $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^n \frac{1} {n+k} \geq \frac{1} {2}$$

Induction step: $n \rightarrow n+1$

$$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1} {n+1+k} \geq \frac{1} {2}$$

$$ \left( \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} \frac{1} {n+1+k} \right) + \frac{1} {n+1+n+1} \geq \frac{1} {2}$$

Comment: I have seen a similar problem before.

Comment: @MathLover It was true when MathLover last saw it and if it was true then, it's true now - therefore it's true, by induction

Comment: @Carl  Let's start with how far you got.  Please include the base case, and write the induction hypothesis.  Start with that, and we can review it, and help.

Comment: You have the sum of $n$ positive terms, the smallest of them equals $\frac{1}{2n}$, hence induction is not really necessary. The claim is trivial.

Comment: I frorgot to precise that the proo has to be for $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$

Comment: @Carl the sum has no sense for$ n=0$ so n is at least $\geq 1$

Comment: Well, I guess we'll just go and search for the duplicate**s**

Comment: @Kelenner thats exactly the problem why this is so particulary difficult to proove. The problem is that if you try to get one out of $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1} {(n+1)+k}$, you get $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} \frac{1} {(n+1)+k}$ and $\frac{1} {(n+1)+n+1}$ . You cant get a $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} \frac{1} {n+k}$ sum. Else it would be very easy :)

Comment: @Carl.  I was able to upload the image of your work.  Once you get more proficient in using mathjax on this site, you can come back and transcribe the image directly into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by induction: Take your base case as $n=1$. Then LHS becomes $\frac12\ge\frac12$.

Then assume $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+n}\ge\frac12$$ Then you are left to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{k+n+1}\ge\frac12$$

$$LHS=\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}-\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}$$  Then $$\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(2)(n+1)+(n+1)(2n+1)-(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}\\=\frac{2n^2+4n+2+2n^2+3n+1-4n^2-6n-2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}=\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}>0$$ Thus $LHS\ge\frac12$ for the $k+1$ case.

Comment: thank You but I'm way further than that. The problem is that you can't get a $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} \frac{1} {n+k}$ sum.

Comment: @Carl I didn't include all the steps to start with because it wasn't clear from your question how much work you had done. Having seen the edit, I have edited the answer to include these steps, hopefully it makes sense :)

Comment: Yes thank you very much @John Doe $\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{k+n+1}$ was just the genius step i didn't thought of :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to prove this with an inductive argument, since (as **Jack D'Aurizio** points out), you can more easily prove it without induction.

Here's one way of doing it. Define $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$. Establishing the base case is easy so all we need is the inductive case:

$$\begin{aligned}S(n)
&=\frac{1}{n/(n-1)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)+(n-1)k/n}\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{n/(n-1)}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)+(n-1)/n}+\color{red}{\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)+(n-1)k/n}}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{n/(n-1)}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)+(n-1)/n}+\color{blue}{S(n-1)}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{(n-1)}{n}S(n-1)
\end{aligned}$$

It's not too hard to show that if $S>\frac12$, then $\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{(n-1)}{n}S\right)>\frac12$ too.

---

To explain where this reasoning came from: We need to relate $S(n)$ to $S(n-1)$. We would want each summand to be $\frac{1}{(n-1)+\ldots}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n+\ldots}$. So lets multiply $S(n)$ by $\frac{(n-1)}{n}\cdot\frac{(n)}{n-1}$. I'll show how we can do this for $S(3)$.

$$\begin{aligned}S(3)
&=\frac{1}{3+1}+\frac{1}{3+2}+\frac{1}{3+3}
\\&=\frac{1}{3/2}\left(\frac{1}{2+2/3}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2+4/3}+\frac{1}{2+6/3}}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{3/2}\left(\frac{1}{2+2/3}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2+2}}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{3/2}\left(\frac{1}{2+2/3}+S(2)\right)
\\&>0.64\ldots
\\&\text{(using $S(2)=0.58\ldots$)}
\end{aligned}$$

Clearly $4/3>1$ and $6/3\geq2$ so we can replace those two red terms with the two blue terms. But also $S(2)=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2+2}$, so we managed to relate $S(3)$ to $S(2)$. Can we do the same for $S(4)$? Yes, we can:

$$\begin{aligned}S(4)
&=\frac{1}{4/3}\left(\frac{1}{3+3/4}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{3+6/4}+\frac{1}{3+9/4}+\frac{1}{3+12/4}}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{4/3}\left(\frac{1}{3+3/4}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{3+1}+\frac{1}{3+2}+\frac{1}{3+3}}\right)
\\&>\frac{1}{4/3}\left(\frac{1}{3+3/4}+S(3)\right)
\\&>0.68\ldots
\end{aligned}$$